# how to build a proper window object in java

Tags: java, command-line-interface

hi i am building a cli application that prints input to the user in each stage and tghe user ahave a few option to choose from the user type the option index and the program respone according.in addition the user can always go back to the prevoious stage and type a diffrent input that wont be effected by the previous input he typed. the question is how can i do that without wasting so much memory saving all the previous stages in some queue and not repeating the sdame code more then once

Answer (score 0):

Before you spend lots of time on optimizing memory utilization, you need to *measure* how much memory will actually be used in storage the stages.  Unless you have measured it (or have a *good* estimate), you risk wasting your time on optimizing something that doesn't need optimizing.

Having said that, if you don't want to store the previous stages, just store the user's inputs for each stage in the queue.  If the user needs to backtrack to a previous stage, you can go back to the start stage and replay the inputs until you reach the stage the user wants.